# How to enable/disable Windows Sonic with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, audio, surround-sound

I really like to play with **Windows Sonic** enabled but sometimes I need it to be disabled.

How can I enable/disable (**toggle**) it using keyboard shortcut f.ex.<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> ?

Information about what is Windows Sonic :

> Windows Sonic is Microsoft’s platform-level solution for spatial sound support (...) enabling both surround and elevation (above or below the listener) audio cues.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/spatial-sound

Comment: What is "Windows Sonic"?

Comment: @music2myear I have added information about what it is to the question.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? Ideally i would like a clickable shortcut to toggle it, or two to turn it on and off.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution.